# How to position items relative to each other in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am trying to figure out how to position the button relative to the text.

```
package windows;

import javax.swing.*;

public class window {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Some Text");
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In other words I want to position the button below wherever the text is.

Comment: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: If you follow the link provided by @JorgeCampos you will see there are a number of ways (different layout managers) to achieve the required positioning. Another thing to keep in mind is that we can combine layout managers by adding a panel (e.g. with the button and label) with one layout into another panel with a different layout. Doing so might make it easier to ensure that the button and label fulfil the requirement of being close to, and one above the other.

Comment: Even not too needed at this point I sarted working in a very simple swing implementation of the Android's Relative Layout. It is very amazing, once you can write very big interfaces with a easy code. You can check my drafts here: [JRelativeLayout](https://github.com/LucasAlfare/JRelativeLayout). It is not too clean but I'm porting it to Kotlin now! :)